# Redux saga and immutablejs

Tags: redux, immutable.js, redux-saga

I have created a basic authorization flow using redux, redux-saga and immutable js.

Redux form (v6.0.0-rc.4) allows the form to create an immutable map. I'm passing these values to redux-saga, where I'm trying to pass these values to my login functions.

**Question 1**: Conceptually, when is the appropriate time to use `values.get('username')` to access the data inside an immutable map? Inside my saga, in the function? Should I be looking to wait until the last possible step to extract the values?

**Question 2**: Assuming I am able to extract the values at the right place, I'm not sure I see how this should be handled within the sagas - this is my saga for loginFlow:

```
export function* loginFlow(data) {
  while (true) {
    yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);

    const winner = yield race({
      auth: call(authorize, { data, isRegistering: false }),
      logout: take(LOGOUT),
    });

    if (winner.auth) {
      yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: true });
      forwardTo('/account');
    } else if (winner.logout) {
      yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: false });
      yield call(logout);
      forwardTo('/');
    }

  }
}
```

With `data` being the immutable map from redux-form. However, whenever I console log `data` in my sagas, it only ever returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I wasn't handling passing the immutable Map to the action correctly - correct code:

```
export function* loginFlow() {

  while (true) {

    // this line ensures that the payload from the action
    // is correctly passed through the saga

    const { data } = yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);

    const winner = yield race({

      // this line passes the payload to the login/auth action

      auth: call(authorize, { data, isRegistering: false }),
      logout: take(LOGOUT),
    });

    if (winner.auth) {
      yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: true });
      forwardTo('/account');
    } else if (winner.logout) {
      yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: false });
      yield call(logout);
      forwardTo('/');
    }
  }
}
```